# Does heroku provide free unlimited dynamic website hosting?

Tags: web, heroku, hosting

As the title/question says, I would like to know if Heroku allows me to permanently host a dynamic website for free forever (unless something happens).

I heard of glitch and Heroku and as an entry-level web dev, I would like to dabble in different tech. I heard Heroku does free hosting of "apps". I would like to know if all these conditions are met:

- my website is up and running 24/7 all the time
- supports a dynamic website (and bootstrap support)
- forever free with no fee (unless I upgrade)
- is there a limit to how much I can add to my website?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## shot answer NO

heroku does provide free service but you can't rely on it for hosting
the site won't be up 24\7

Answer (score -1):

I use Heroku free option as well. As far as I know, there is no time limit but you do have only 500mb of RAM. 
In a course on Udemy where I heard about Heroku, the instructor said that you can use the free version if you are not expecting more than a couple hundred visits a day. But I have no idea how correct that is.

A bigger issue to me is the fact that you dont get a SSL certificate so your website is not secure, which might be okay for a portfolio website. But even then it might be a good idea to go for the first paying option